# Trouble writing arch-linux.iso with USB-Imager software

Tags: hard-drive, usb, arch-linux, iso-image

I recently corrupted my hard disk while partitioning it and I couldn't boot in my Arch Linux installation. I repartitioned my hard disk drive by booting from an already existing `.iso file`, but this didn't resolve my issues. So now my intention was to reinstall `Arch Linux` from scratch. However, when I use the `UsbImager` software, I run into problems. Here is its `gitlab` repo: https://gitlab.com/bztsrc/usbimager

It used to work because I have done this a few times already, but now it doesn't.

So the software provides a very simple GUI, just where to put the `.iso` and the flash drive. Both are properly detected. However, when I press `Write`, the following error occurs: `An error occured while opening the device`. I tried using another flash drive and even another machine but the same error happened over and over again. Since that didn't work, I decided to `shred` my flash drive (remove everything on there). I went [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org%20%E2%80%BA%20title%20%E2%80%BA%20USB_flash_installation_medium) and checked terminal commands with `cp` and so on but I have trouble figuring out how this works.

I appreciate any insights!

Comment: Can't tell why it worked before, and not now, but my go-to boot USB makers are Rufus, https://rufus.ie/, and UNetbootin, https://unetbootin.github.io/, and others like these alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/rufus/ . If you're having trouble with UsbImager, try the standards.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Ok I'll try. Thanks